# Remove all items from UITabBarController

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, uitabbarcontroller

I'd like to remove all items from UITabBarController within MainWindow. I can achieve it this way:

```
self.tabViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray array];
self.tabViewController.customizableViewControllers = [NSArray array];
```

But what about old controllers that was there? Is this more correct way?

```
- (void)cleanCurrentTabbar {
    for (id ctrl in self.tabViewController.customizableViewControllers) {
        [ctrl release];
    }
    for (id ctrl in self.tabViewController.viewControllers) {
        [ctrl release];
    }
    self.tabViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray array];
    self.tabViewController.customizableViewControllers = [NSArray array];
}
```

Comment: You don't need to release viewControllers of your tabbar. If you access the property .customizableViewControllers/.viewControllers by setting a new value to it then within the setter method the old value of this property is released by default. So setting [NSArray array] as a new value suffices.

Comment: @TRD it releases an array... isn't it? And I want to release items within array.

Comment: But if you release an array a release message to all containing items will be sent, because the array has retained his items while adding them and so the array is responsible for releasing, not you.

Comment: @TRD ic.. I'll do some research about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Parth Bhatt told, releasing `viewControllers` items looks like good idea. Maybe. But in my case it leads to the strange `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` errors:
[image]
So I end up with `self.tabViewController.viewControllers = nil;` and its works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your second option is more correct concept wise as well with respect to memory management because it releases all allocated resources before making it nil.

But rather than giving it an empty array which is in itself an autoreleased object like [NSArray array], you can assign `nil`.

```
- (void)cleanCurrentTabbar {
    for (id ctrl in self.tabViewController.customizableViewControllers) {
        [ctrl release];
    }
    for (id ctrl in self.tabViewController.viewControllers) {
        [ctrl release];
    }
    self.tabViewController.viewControllers = nil;
    self.tabViewController.customizableViewControllers = nil;
}
```

Also as James Webster has said in blow comment:

"You may or may not need to release depending on the type of property viewControllers and customizableViewControllers are"

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Careful, you may not need to release depending on the type of property viewControllers and customizableViewControllers are

Comment: It's `@property(nonatomic,copy) NSArray *viewControllers;`

Comment: @James Webster: Sorry to have missed out on that point you are right. I have edited my answer an added that. Please check it out. Thanks for improving the answer :)

Comment: @NilColor: Then you will need to release your viewControllers as it has `copy` keyword which increases retainCount by 1. Hope this helps you.:). And Yeah, What about the customizablViewControllers?

Comment: `customizablViewControllers` is `copy` property to.  Thanks @Parth Bhatt and @James Webster.

Comment: @NilColor: You're Welcome. I am really glad that it helped. :) As of for `customizablViewControllers` also you need to release them. So your second code is fine except the `[NSArray array]`

Comment: Yeah. I use `nil`, not empty array.

Comment: @Parth Bhatt sorry but i'll have to unmark this answer... releasing `tabViewController.viewControllers` leads to unpredictable `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` errors. So no, I don't have to release controllers myself...

Comment: Dont be Sorry..! No problem mate..! Its totally upto you. I still feel it is the right way to  do this. Anyways thanks.. :)

Answer (score 0):

That's cleaner in terms of memory yes. You should release objects when you are finished with them, that includes before reassigning.

However, I notice you are using self.tabViewController.viewControllers. Is that property assign or retain? If it's retain, the release will be done internally.

Comment: It's `@property(nonatomic,copy) NSArray *viewControllers;`

Comment: I know copy increases the retain count of an object, but I'm not sure it decreases it when used in a property. I expect it does, but you may want to research that further

Comment: @James Webster:  `copy` is used so viewControllers needs to be released.